# apprise implementation, referencing $(this) from outside current scope

Tags: jquery, scope, this

Im a super noob to jQuery and web development in general and need some help implementing the apprise alert system.  I realize that the functions within the "verify" function do not recognize the "this" selector and that I should implement $.proxy to get the "this" selector from outside of the current scope.  But no matter what I try I cant get this to work

```
$('.closebtn').click(function(){

            apprise('<center>Are you sure you want to delete this section?<br>This action can not be undone!</center>',{'verify':true}, function(r){
                if(r){
                     $(this).remove();
                }
            })
 })
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Simple, store `this`.

```
$('.closebtn').click(function(){
  var $button = $(this);

  apprise(...., function(r){
    if (r){
      // re-reference it
      $button.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

You may see "classes" in javascript do something similar to this as well (usually named `self`). e.g.

```
var myObject = function(){
  var self = this;

  var MyMethod = function(){
    // can use "self" in here to reference the object
  };
};
```

Comment: Thx for the help.  I tried that and it didnt work and I thought I was losing my mind.  But there was actually more code involved and on mouseleave and it was removing the click event handler when I moved the mouse pointer to the apprise popup window...thx for confirming that I could store 'this' to a variable like that tho